# Find all positive integers $x,y,z$ such that $x!+y!+z!$ is a multiple of $x+y+z$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

So I came across this problem on the internet and it's not meant to be a super hard problem (I think), but I just don't know how to proceed with this problem. What I tried is that I assumed $x \le y \le z$ and then $$x! +y! +z! = n(x+y+z)$$ $$\implies 1 + \frac{y!}{x!} + \frac{z!}{x!} = n\frac{x+y+z}{x!} \ge 3$$
And similarly
$$\frac{x!}{z!} + \frac{y!}{z!} + 1 = n\frac{x+y+z}{z!} \le 3$$
But I don't what conclusions to ddraw  from this or if this is the right direction at all. Thanks.

Comment: There are certainly a large number of solutions—for example, for any given $x$, one can take any $y,z\ge x$ such that $x+y+z$ divides $x!$. For $x=10$ alone this yields $15{,}329{,}113$ solutions.

Comment: I see, thanks. Could you perhaps tell me how you got the number of solutions if it's not a trouble?

Comment: If we permit $x=y=z$, tjem by inspection we can see that
\begin{align*}
(1+1+1)=3  &\space |\space (1+1+1)=3\\
(2+2+2)=6  &\space |\space (2+2+2)=6\\
(3+3+3)=9  &\space |\space (6+6+6)=18\\
(4+4+4)=12 &\space |\space (24+24+24)=72\\
(5+5+5)=15 &\space |\space (120+120+120)=360\\
           &\large{\vdots}\\
\end{align*}

So it appears that $x,y,z\in\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For  $\quad x<y<z,\quad$ we have
\begin{align*}
(5+12+13)=30  &\space |\space (5!+12!+13!)=6706022520\\
(8+15+17)=40  &\space |
\space (8!+15!+17!)=356995102504320\\
(7+24+25)=56  &\space |
\space (7!+24!+25!)\\
&\space \space  =16131658445064225423365040
\\
(9+40+41)=90  &\space |
\space (9!+40!+41!)\\
=&34268441896411704842515673323036867559424000362880
\\
(12+35+37)=90  &\space |
\space (12!+35!+37 !)\\
=& 13774086239192731191245646232918425600040320
\\
(20+21+29)=70  &\space |
\space (20!+21!+29!)\\
&\space \space  =8841761993793225798723502080000\\
&\large{\vdots}
\end{align*}

These are Pythagorean triples where $x^2+y^2=z^2$ and, while $(3,4,5)$ does not work, these are the next larger ones by area and it can be expected that there are more triples to  be found with Wolfram Alpha as shown
[here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2820%21%2B21%21%2B29%21%29+%2F70).

Comment: Thanks, I don't think we can make it more specific than this.